# How to load base64 encoded text into an XML document using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How can I load base64 encoded text into an XML document using XSLT?

For instance, if I had the following two documents

**input file 1:**

```
YTM0NZomIzI2OTsmIzM0NTueYQ==
```

**input file 2:**

```
<xml>
<Column1></Column1>
</xml>
```

**desired output:**

```
<xml>
<Column1>YTM0NZomIzI2OTsmIzM0NTueYQ==</Column1>
</xml>
```

Comment: The way SO works is you try to solve the problem first, then ask a specific question when you have difficulties, showing what you have done.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **XSLT 2.0**, you can use the [`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text) function to load the base64 content from the text file.

In the example below, an `xsl:param` is set with a default value for the document URI, but a different value could be set when invoking the transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="base64-document" select="'base64-content.txt'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Column1">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text($base64-document)"/>
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you can't use XSLT 2.0, then in **XSLT 1.0** you could use a third XML file with an entity reference to the base64 text file to include it's the content in the third XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Column1">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="document('thirdFile.xml')/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also read the contents of the base64 text file(outside the context of XSLT) and send the content as the value of an `xsl:param`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="base64-content" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Column1">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$base64-content"/>
      </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Getting this error : javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: unparsed-text
please help ?

Comment: Sounds like you are using an XSLT 1.0 engine. unparsed-text() is a 2.0 only function. Either use a 2.0 capable engine (like Saxon) or try my 1.0 solution